# php to display text as html formated stored in database

Tags: php, html

I have one text saved in MySQL Database

```
<p> Celebrate with these amazing<br /> offers direct from the
```

Now when I print that text using

```
echo
```

I got this output

```
 <p> Celebrate with these amazing<br /> offers direct from the
```

but U want to display that as

```
Celebrate with these amazing
 offers direct from the
```

like HTML print.

when i see in db its stored like bellow

```
&lt;p&gt;
    Celebrate with these amazing&lt;br /&gt;
    offers from
```

How to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that into database is stored the <p> Cel....<br /> ... and not the &lt;p&gt; Cel...&lt;br/&gt; ... ??

Comment: Agree with @MerianosNikos, looks like your DB has stored the escaped html tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your database has saved the escaped information like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;
    Celebrate with these amazing&lt;br /&gt;
    offers from
```

Then you could just use PHP's [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function to output that block of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help you http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/qt/php_in_mysql.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you are outputting to the console (it's not clear from your question what you are trying to output to):

If you look at the PHP strip_tags documentation, you should be able to reach something approximating what you want.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

With strip_tags(), you can allow the 
 tag to remain and then replace it with "\n" afterwards.

Otherwise, if you are outputting to browser, then other posts on this page have the answer - you must be storing the htmlentities() version of the data in the database.